# Поиск по внешнему ключу Django

Tags: python, django, search

Обучаюсь django и столкнулся с проблемой: есть поиск по таблице с записями из бд на сайте и нужно его реализовать по всем полям, но никак не могу реализовать его по forigin key.

```
'''View.py'''

search_query_date = request.GET.get('search_date', '')
search_query_text = request.GET.get('search_text', '')

if (search_query_text or search_query_date == None):
    orders = Order.objects.filter(Q(adress__icontains=search_query_text) | Q(customer=search_query_text)).order_by('-date')
elif (search_query_text or search_query_date):
    orders = Order.objects.filter(Q(adress__icontains=search_query_text) | Q(date__icontains=search_query_date)).order_by('-date')
else:
    orders = Order.objects.order_by('-date')
```

Модель:

```
'''model.py'''


class Order(models.Model):
  customer = models.ForeignKey(Сustomer, verbose_name="Заказчик", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name="Продукт", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
  quantity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Количество", null=True, blank=True)
  final_price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Итоговая стоимость", null=True, blank=True)
  adress = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Адрес")
```

Т.е. например введя в поле поиска "Иван" получить не ошибку "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Иван'.", а вернуть его по полю name из зависимой таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если предположить, что имя храниться в поле `name` класса `Customer`, то

```
Q(customer__name=search_query_text)
```